# How can I re-attach rear muffler pipe to muffler body

Tags: subaru, exhaust, diy, muffler

2004 Impreza Subaru Outback Sport (2.5L SOHC)

The rear pipe of my muffler has broken away from from its weld to the muffler body. I would just replace the whole muffler assembly, but the joint where the muffler pipe meets the rear exhaust (#13 in picture) is severely rusted, and I worry about dominoes all the way to the engine if I try to replace it.

[image: Subaru Muffler]

Is there a way to re-affix the pipe to the muffler without welding? I'm imagining a pipe adapter that fits around the pipe and steps down a quarter inch or so to fit inside the muffler body. Could then seal it all up with JB Weld or RTV?

Thanks!

Comment: Uh, RTV is not the proper repair for exhaust systems. Get it welded. I suspect it's all rotted and can't be welded though, in which case, take it to an exhaust shop. Maybe they can fab something cheaper than an OEM part. They can deal with a rusty #13 connection.

Comment: "without welding" Yeah, just get it permanently fixed. It's always surprised me how cheap an exhaust shop will do a weld. Your average exhaust chain store may not have a decent metal worker. You may need to call around in your area and look up reviews.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for can be found by googling "exhuast repair kit."  It's essentially a sleeve with 2 clamps that you fit over or under (depending on the design) your affected exhaust section.  Assuming there is nothing left on the muffler side, you'll only be using the 1 clamp.  "Exhaust repair sealant," is the goo you are looking for to seal the whole thing up.  This may require cutting a bit of your old exhaust away.

This is not what I would call a high quality repair.

JB weld or RTV are NOT what you are looking for, exhaust gets very hot.  It might work for a litle while; JBweld's FAQ suggests it is okay to use far enough away from the cat and manifold.  RTV is really only good in thin layers, I worry this would be too large a hole for it to fill.  I wouldn't recommend it, but depends how "good" this repair needs to be.

Shop around; There is a good chance you can get it profesionally welded very reasonably, rather than having to shell out again once the repair sleeve fails.